# Determining the values of beta in a logistic regression equation

Tags: math, statistics, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I read about logistic regression on Wikipedia and it talks of the equation where z, the output depends on the values of beta1, beta2, beta3, and so on which are termed as regression coefficients along with beta0, which is the intercept.

How do you determine the values of these coefficients and intercept given a sample set where we know the output probability and the values of the input dependent factors?

Comment: There are various ways of estimating the intercept and coefficients; one of them is [using a linear SVM training algorithm](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/modules/generated/scikits.learn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

Comment: Would you be happy to provide few references here please? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: My previous comment contained a link. See also http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/logreg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use R.  Here's a video: www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yv05RjKpEKY